# How to return the sub modules html

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I have a multi module spring boot project. The structure now is

```
Parent
 |- FrontFacingApp
    |- UserAccountCreationModule
    |- SomeOtherBusinessModule
```

The structure earlier was each of the modules were an independent application. We want `FrontFacingApp` to be the user facing app.`UserAccountCreationModule` and other sub modules are a dependency within the `FrontFacingApp`. All modules have their own `@Controllers` and `src/main/resources/templates` folder which contains html files served by thymeleaf. Everything was ticking along fine, till we wanted an `index.html` in the `FrontFacingApp`.

Now, when the application receives a request for `/getUserAccountIndex` the `@Controller` within the `UserAccountCreationModule` module returns `"index"` (which is an html file in `UserAccountCreationModule /src/main/resources/templates/index.html`). However what the user ends up being served is the index file from the `FrontFacingApp`. So, the front facing app returns its own `index.html` which lives in `FrontFacingApp /src/main/resources/templates/index.html`, which was supposed to be returned by the request mapping for `/getFrontFacingIndex` (by a controller in the front facing app).

Its easy enough to rename the `index.html` and what is returned from the controller within the `UserAccountCreationModule` for this issue - but I want to understand how is Spring Boot deciding which index html is returned? And how could I go about returning the submodule's `index.html`. Can the scope of the `@Controller` be contained to return whatever is within a submodule?